# R Webscraping: How to feed URLS into a function

Tags: r, web-scraping

My end goal is to be able to take all 310 articles from this page and its following [pages](https://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/advanced-search?field-keywords=%22space%20exploration%22&field-keywords2=&field-keywords3=&from%5Bdate%5D=&to%5Bdate%5D=&person2=&items_per_page=100) and run it through this function:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

scrape_docs <- function(URL){
  doc <- read_html(URL)

  speaker <- html_nodes(doc, ".diet-title a") %>% 
    html_text()

  date <- html_nodes(doc, ".date-display-single") %>%
    html_text() %>%
    mdy()

  title <- html_nodes(doc, "h1") %>%
    html_text()

  text <- html_nodes(doc, "div.field-docs-content") %>%
    html_text()

  all_info <- list(speaker = speaker, date = date, title = title, text = text)

  return(all_info)
}
```

I assume the way to go forward would be to somehow create a list of the URLs I want, then iterate that list through the `scrape_docs` function. As it stands, however, I'm having a hard time understanding how to go about that. I thought something like this would work, but I seem to be missing something key given the following error:

> xml_attr cannot be applied to object of class "character'.

```r
source_col <- "https://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/advanced-search?field-keywords=%22space%20exploration%22&field-keywords2=&field-keywords3=&from%5Bdate%5D=&to%5Bdate%5D=&person2=&items_per_page=100&page=0"

pages <- 4
all_links <- tibble()

for(i in seq_len(pages)){
  page <- paste0(source_col,i) %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_attr("href") %>%
    html_attr()

  tmp <- page[[1]]

  all_links <- bind_rows(all_links, tmp)
}

all_links
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the url's by doing

```
library(rvest)

source_col <- "https://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/advanced-search?field-keywords=%22space%20exploration%22&field-keywords2=&field-keywords3=&from%5Bdate%5D=&to%5Bdate%5D=&person2=&items_per_page=100&page=0"

all_urls <- source_col %>%
              read_html() %>%
              html_nodes("td a") %>%
              html_attr("href") %>%
             .[c(FALSE, TRUE)] %>%
              paste0("https://www.presidency.ucsb.edu", .)
```

Now do the same by changing the page number in `source_col` to get remaining data.

You can then use a `for` loop or `map` to extract all the data.

```
purrr::map(all_urls, scrape_docs)
```

Testing the function `scrape_docs` on 1 URL

```
scrape_docs(all_urls[1])

#$speaker
#[1] "Dwight D. Eisenhower"

#$date
#[1] "1958-04-02"

#$title
#[1] "Special Message to the Congress Relative to Space Science and Exploration."

#$text
#[1] "\n    To the Congress of the United States:\nRecent developments in long-range 
#    rockets for military purposes have for the first time provided man with new mac......
```